# No suitable module for running kernal found

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I am new to Linux and really hit a wall with this one. I'm basically trying to set up VirtualBox for Vagrant. I had this working yesterday but today its not after I rebuilt my pc.

I have tried to start and stop the service but still the same errors message.

> lsb_release - a = Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS ( desktop version ) release 14.04
>
> codename trust
>
> uname -r
>
> 3.19.0 -25-generic

I have follow troubleshooting guides on this forum
[14.10: VirtualBox "No suitable module for running kernel found", Cannot Find Kernel Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582109/14-10-virtualbox-no-suitable-module-for-running-kernel-found-cannot-find-ker)

and these steps

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms 
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-dkms 
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

I really don't know enough to solve this. Any help would be appreciated? I'm so fed up I would actually pay someone to talk me through it

Comment: This is not a real solution. But have you tried Virtualbox 5. (http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/07/install-virtualbox-5-0-ubuntu-15-04-14-04-12-04/)