# Virtualbox * No suitable module for running kernel found [fail]

Tags: apt, updates, 15.04, sudo, update-manager

Previously I had ubuntu 15.04. I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS as I was told the 14.04 was stable.

Now when I try to install Virtual Box this error is shown:

```
vatsa@code-8-21:~$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox
Readingpackage lists... Done
Building dependency tree  
    Reading state information... Done
The following extra packageswill be installed:
  virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
Suggestedpackages:
  virtualbox-guest-additions-iso vde2
Thefollowing NEW packages will be installed:
  virtualboxvirtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 toremove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/20.6 MB ofarchives.
After this operation, 84.1 MB of additional disk spacewill be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selectingpreviously unselected package virtualbox.
(Reading database ...225930 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing tounpack .../virtualbox_4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
Selectingpreviously unselected package virtualbox-dkms.
Preparing tounpack .../virtualbox-dkms_4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5_all.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
Selectingpreviously unselected package virtualbox-qt.
Preparing to unpack.../virtualbox-qt_4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpackingvirtualbox-qt (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers forureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on nextreboot
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1)...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Settingup virtualbox (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...


 * StoppingVirtualBox kernel modules                      [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules
 * No suitable module for running kernel found            [fail]


invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
Setting up virtualbox-dkms(4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
Loading new virtualbox-4.3.10 DKMSfiles...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.19.0-31-generic
Building initial module for3.19.0-31-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad returnstatus for module build on kernel: 3.19.0-31-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/make.log for moreinformation.


 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                     [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules
 * No suitable module for running kernel found            [fail]


invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
Setting up virtualbox-qt (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5)...
```

please help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [14.10: VirtualBox "No suitable module for running kernel found", Cannot Find Kernel Source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/582109/14-10-virtualbox-no-suitable-module-for-running-kernel-found-cannot-find-ker)

Comment: What worked for me personally is to manually install virtualbox from their official site. Try that

Answer (score 2):

I am also running ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.19.0. What worked for me was manually grabbing the .deb package from virtualbox for vbox 4.3.34.

This can then be installed 'sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file'

Hope this helps