# Install linux-signed-image-generic for the latest mainline kernel

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I installed the [latest kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.1/) with [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/963779/34298) but now my VirtualBox doesn't work. When I start the current kernel 4.13.0-17 and run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
```

VirtualBox runs fine, so I guess I need the signed kernel too (as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/673458/34298)), but how do I install it for the latest kernel?

Edit: for 4.14.1 it sais

```
Building initial module for 4.14.1-041401-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.14.1-041401-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.14.1-041401-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.30/build/make.log for more information.
```

Comment: does VB have any kernel modules that need to be compiled to the new kernel?

Comment: yes, for 4.13.0-17 it sais "DKMS: install completed.", for 4.14.1 see above...

Comment: Canonical only signs the official Ubuntu kernels.

Comment: apparently there was a change in the headers, VB won't compile for 4.14, or at least dkms doesn't want to compile for it.

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17080 seems like I have to install a newer VB verison then too? maybe I don't need the signed-kernel then. What are "official Ubuntu kernels" I thought non-rc kernels would be official?

Comment: official kernels are the ones in the repo. Daily builds of mainline aren't official.

Comment: So which one is the latest official release?